# save by group predicted values from linear regression to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, prediction

I want to apply linear regression and predict values to subsets of my original data by `V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, and V6`. Then I want to store dataframe with names: `V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, time, Predicted value`. How to achieve it effificiently? What I have now gives me an object that is hard to further work with.

```
def model(df):     
    X = df['time'].to_numpy().reshape((-1, 1))
    Y = df['speed'].to_numpy() 
    X_new = np.arange(1, 60, 1).reshape((-1, 1))
    return np.squeeze(LinearRegression().fit(X, Y).predict(X_new))

def group_predictions(df): 
    return df.groupby(['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5','V6']).apply(model)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output must be a Series of numpy arrays, so `explode()` should do the trick.

However, `time` cannot be a column in the output because the dimensions won't match. Function `model()` returns the predicted values, so unless the length of each sub-df is 59, `time` cannot be one of the output columns.

```py
def group_predictions(df):
    return df.groupby(['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5','V6']).apply(model).explode().reset_index(name='Predicted value')
```

If `X_new` also must be returned, it's more readable to construct dfs in `model()` itself. Then `group_predictions()` must also be modified to accommodate the fact that `model()` returns a df, not array.

```py
def model(df):     
    X = df['time'].to_numpy().reshape((-1, 1))
    Y = df['speed'].to_numpy() 
    X_new = np.arange(1, 60, 1).reshape((-1, 1))
    return pd.DataFrame({'X_new': X_new.ravel(), 'Predicted value': LinearRegression().fit(X, Y).predict(X_new)})

def group_predictions(df):
    return df.groupby(['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5','V6']).apply(model).droplevel(-1).reset_index()
```